# What are the demo 1 and demo 2 terminals on the oscilloscopes?

Tags: oscilloscope

I have seen almost all oscilloscope providing this demo1 or may be demo2 terminals on their oscilloscopes which has the square wave running all the time? I can't figure out the purpose of those demo terminals?

Comment: They are intended to help [tune the probe](http://www.picotech.com/applications/how-to-tune-x10-oscilloscope-probes.html)

Comment: Which model oscilloscope are you referring to?

Comment: I've never seen a terminal on a scope marked "Demo".  What you describe are usually marked "Cal", and provide a square wave of known amplitude and frequency as an aid to calibrate the probes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Some scopes have "Cal" or "demo"!

Comment: The Agilent DSOX2000 and DSOX3000 have terminals Demo1 and Demo2/Probe cal, maybe you are referring to these?  There is an option for outputting Demo/Training signals on these terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Agilent scopes come with "Demo 1" and "Demo 2/Probe Comp" terminals (little wire loops actually) on the front panel. With the optional Educator's Kit, you can provide demo or training signals on these terminals.

The Demo 2 terminal also "outputs the Probe Comp signal which helps you match a [passive] probe's input capacitance to the oscilloscope channel to which it is connected."

Check the User's and/or Programmer's guide for the scope you're working with. The above information happens to come from the User Guide for the 2000 X-Series and the Programmer's Guide for the 3000 X-Series.